# CentOSで ls * と ?ができない

Tags: linux, centos, shellscript

新しいLinuxの教科書で勉強しているのですが、
`$ ls ba*` と `$ ls ba??` などのコマンドを打っても

```
そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
```

と出てきます。 `ls -1` とか本に出てるように打ってもホームディレクトリにあるファイルが出てきます。
こんな初歩的な部分で躓いてすごい萎えてます...
教えてもらえないでしょうか？

Comment: `ls` の結果、 `ba` のようなファイルやディレクトリは存在しますか？

Comment: 本に書かれているのは `ls -1`(数字の1)ではなくて `ls -l`(英小文字のエル)かもしれません。また `*`, `?` についてはWikipediaの記事 "[グロブ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AD%E3%83%96)"も参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*`や`?`は**ワイルドカード**と呼ばれる特殊な指定方法で、それぞれ

- `*` 任意の0文字以上の文字
- `?` 任意の1文字

にマッチします。

`ls ba*`は「`ba`で始まるファイル名(単なる`ba`も含む)」、`ls ba??`は「`ba`で始まる4文字のファイル名」にマッチしますが、**条件に当てはまるファイルが存在しなければ**「そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」とエラーになります。

単に`ls`と実行してどんなファイルがあるのかを確認してからワイルドカードを使用してみましょう。

もしくは空の適当なファイルを作って実行してみるのもよいでしょう。

```
$ touch bash bash.txt  # touch コマンドで空のファイルを作成
$ ls ba*
bash bash.txt
$ ls ba??
bash

$ rm bash bash.txt     # 必要なくなったら削除
```

Comment: ありがとうございますただbaから始まるファイルがなかっただけでした。centOS入れたら最初から入ってるファイルだと思っててそれが出なくて焦ってましたが助かりました。。

Comment: @DJCowardice さん、この回答で問題を解決したら回答の承認をお願いします。他の質問でも承認を行っていないようですが、解決したものについては同様に承認をしてください。 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)